# gtkmm 3 Toolbar set orientation

Tags: gtkmm

I just updated my project from gtkmm 2.4 where I would add a toolbar and change it to vertical  via:
    toolbar.set_orientation();

In gtkmm 3.2 this function doesn't exist and I couldn't find anything about it on the "Changes in gtkmm 3.0" page.  I tried placing it in a VBox but Gtk::Toolbar doesn't inherit from Gtk::Orientable so I think perhaps gtk has removed this functionality?  Is there a way to get the old behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Gtkmm 3.4 i can do (the documentation of Gtk 3.2 confirms) :

```
myToolbar->set_property("orientation", Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```

see [gtk/gtktoolbar.c](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtktoolbar.c?h=gtk-3-2) (near line 497: g_object_class_override_property(..., "orientation"))

However, the text of icons appears now. To remove:

```
myToolbar->set_property("toolbar-style", Gtk::TOOLBAR_ICONS);
```

see [gtk_toolbar_set_style](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkToolbar.html#gtk-toolbar-set-style)

Hoping that this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method to change the orientation, but there is a property you can set:

```
toolbar.property_orientation().set_value(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```

Or

```
toolbar.property_orientation() = Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL;
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant gtkmm 3.2 where it looks like both methods have been removed.  [3.0](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.0/classGtk_1_1Toolbar.html), [3.2](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.2/classGtk_1_1Toolbar.html).  Thanks for replying though, it gave me something else to look for.

Comment: It seems gtkmm 3.2 doesn't have toolbar implementing the Orientable interface, while gtk 3.2 does. I don't know why it is like that other than wrap-lag or an over-sight. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your comments.  Perhaps next version will add it back in again :)